# Worksheet object not callable

Tags: openpyxl

I created an excel workbook via openpyxl.
I tried to populate the workbook with some values.
So I wrote some codes to achieve this goal,but I encountered a program crash
and could not achieve my goal.

Below are the codes:

```
import openpyxl
wb=openpyxl.Workbook()
sheet=wb.active
sheet['A1']=200
sheet['A2']=300
sheet['A3']= '=SUM(A1:A2)'
wb.save('Formular.xlsx')
```

After running the code,I received an error message pointing to the third line
of the code and below is the error message.It seems I did something wrong.
PLEASE HOW CAN I FIX THIS?

TypeError: 'Worksheet' object is not callable

Comment: The exception does not match the code: please provide the complete traceback.

Comment: I have successfully fixed the problem.Thanks Charlie

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code, it will work:

```
import openpyxl
wb=openpyxl.Workbook()
sheet=wb.active
sheet['A1']=200
sheet['A2']=300
sheet['A3']= '=SUM(A1:A2)' 
wb.save(filename = 'Formular.xlsx')
```